# React app's routing works fine in development but get 404 in production (PythonAnywhere)

Tags: reactjs, flask, pythonanywhere

I've got React app set up on PythonAnywhere which is working fine locally but
get 404 when built on PythonAnywhere.

directory structure:

```
client/     
project/
     __init__.py
     config.py
     api/
         blog.py
         models.py
     
static/
     react/          # All React files created in this react directory upon build
         css/
         js/
templates/
     index.html      # index file created upon build
tests/
```

blog.py:

```
blog_blueprint = Blueprint('blog', __name__, url_prefix='/blog', static_folder='../../static/react', template_folder='../../templates')

@blog_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', token='hakuna matata'), 200
```

snippet of init file:

```
def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(current_config)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development':
        toolbar.init_app(app)
    login_mgr.init_app(app)
    login_mgr.session_protection = "strong"
    mail.init_app(app)

    from project.api.blog import blog_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(blog_blueprint)

    return app


app = create_app()
```

I've tried to turn the debug mode on but that didn't give me any helpful pointers.

Error log:

```
NameError: name 'DevelopmentConfig' is not defined
File "/var/www/tech_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-02-17 01:07:46,625:     from project import app as application  # noqa
2021-02-17 01:07:46,625: 
2021-02-17 01:07:46,626:   File "/home/markalexa/blog/project/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
2021-02-17 01:07:46,626:     app = create_app()
2021-02-17 01:07:46,626: 
2021-02-17 01:07:46,626:   File "/home/markalexa/blog/project/__init__.py", line 35, in create_app
2021-02-17 01:07:46,626:     app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
```

This error output says that the config isn't defined despite being present in the `config.py` file and being in the right directory. It says `DevelopmentConfig` because I turned the debug mode on to get more insight into the 404 error.

Network tab in Firefox:

[image]

Thank you for any advice.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed my `BrowserRouter` to `HashRouter` as it appears to be recommended to use it in production since HashRouter uses hashHistory which handles wildcard addresses. Nonetheless, my routes still throw 404.

Have added a catch-all function to the init file which redirects all unrecognized requests to index:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_error(e):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Still getting 404 ...

Comment: `DevelopmentConfig` NameError is the only error that can be seen in your question. Fix it first.

Comment: Yes, I switched back to `ProductionConfig` so the error is gone but 404 error didn't go away. I didn't post any other errors because I'm not getting any except from the 404.

Comment: Access log is showing only request responses 404 which again isn't very helpful.

Comment: What do you see in your dev tools in the browser. What is it looking for so it is getting 404? Is it in the / url of your web app?

Comment: I can see no routes are working. Not just root route. It's almost as if `BrowserRouter` I'm using isn't working at all.

Comment: I've tried to access backend on the port 5000 where I temporarily return "output" but when I try to load it to have it returned it just keeps looping and no response.

Comment: I've added output from the network tab in the browser. Suggesting that the error may originating from `context.js` file if I'm reading it right.

Comment: You're using relative path names for your static directory and your templates directory. Have you set the working directory for your web app to be the correct directory so that the relative paths are pointing to the right places?